# Return Outlook MAPIFolder type using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I create a folder if it does not exist in my set of Outlook directories with the below code.

```
Private Sub addOutlookFolderIfNotExists()
     Set apOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
     apOutlook.Session.Logon
     Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
     Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder
     Dim myNewFolder As Outlook.Folder

     Set myNameSpace = apOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
     Set myFolder = 
    myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Estimates")
     For i = 1 To myFolder.Folders.Count
        If myFolder.Folders.Item(i).Name = "Testing" Then
           Exit Sub
        End If
     Next

     addOutlookFolderIfNotExists = myFolder.Folders.Add("Testing")
End Sub
```

I would like to use the properties of the folder afterwards. I would like to return the MAPIFolder object just created.  I changed the sub to a function to look like the below.

```
Private Function addOutlookFolderIfNotExists() As MAPIFolder
    Set apOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    apOutlook.Session.Logon
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myNewFolder As Outlook.Folder

    Set myNameSpace = apOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Estimates")
    For i = 1 To myFolder.Folders.Count
        If myFolder.Folders.Item(i).Name = "Testing" Then
            'Debug.Print TypeName(myFolder.Folders.Item(i))
            addOutlookFolderIfNotExists = myFolder.Folders.Item(i)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

    addOutlookFolderIfNotExists = myFolder.Folders.Add("Testing")
End Function
```

This returns an error

> vba object variable or with block variable not set

but I don't know what it's referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it incorrectly. Even the `For` loop is incorrect. The correct way to set or assign an object is to use the command `SET`

Is this what you are trying?

```
Private Function addOutlookFolderIfNotExists() As MAPIFolder
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myNewFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim i As Long

    Set apOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    apOutlook.Session.Logon

    Set myNameSpace = apOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Estimates")

    For i = 1 To myFolder.Folders.Count
        If myFolder.Folders.Item(i).Name = "Testing" Then
            '~~> Set the folder
            Set addOutlookFolderIfNotExists = myFolder.Folders.Item("Testing")
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

    '~~> Create the folder
    myFolder.Folders.Add ("Testing")

    '~~> Set the folder
    Set addOutlookFolderIfNotExists = myFolder.Folders.Item("Testing")
End Function
```

You can also do the above without the `For` Loop. We will use `On Error Resume Next` in lieu of that.

```
Private Function addOutlookFolderIfNotExists() As MAPIFolder
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myNewFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim i As Long

    Set apOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    apOutlook.Session.Logon

    Set myNameSpace = apOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Estimates")

    '~~> Create the folder if it doesn't exists
    '~~> If it exists then suppress the error message and continue
    On Error Resume Next
    myFolder.Folders.Add ("Testing")
    On Error GoTo 0

    '~~> Set the folder
    Set addOutlookFolderIfNotExists = myFolder.Folders.Item("Testing")
End Function
```